# How to reduce the value of the integers from certain alphanumeric strings?

Tags: c#, string

Say I have a text file or string like

```
string text="Elijah Jordan Wood is an \"American\" actor \"erd1\",
voice actor, DJ, and producer \"erd2\".
He is best \"erd3\" known for his \"erd4\" high-profile \"erd5\" leading role \"erd6\" as
Frodo Baggins \"erd7\" in Peter Jackson's \"erd8\" epic \"erd9\" film trilogy
\"erd10\" The Lord of the Rings \"erd11\"";
```

I want to reduce the numeric value from the strings `\"erd...\"` by 1 after the string `\"erd3\"` i.e. the output string should look like

```
string text_out="Elijah Jordan Wood is an \"American\" actor \"erd1\",
voice actor, DJ, and producer \"erd2\".
He is best \"erd3\" known for his \"erd3\" high-profile \"erd4\" leading role \"erd5\" as
Frodo Baggins \"erd6\" in Peter Jackson's \"erd7\" epic \"erd8\" film trilogy
\"erd9\" The Lord of the Rings \"erd10\"";
```

How can I do this?

**NOTE**: There could be *multiple* `\"erd...\"` strings with the same integer value in the file i.e. there could be multiple `\"erd6\"` in the file and also there is *no fixed order* of appearance of the string `\"erd...\"` in the file i.e. `\"erd6\"` could be the first `\"erd...\"` string in the file, then maybe there is `\"erd2\"` and so on. Also if say, `\"erd6\"` appears before the first `\"erd3\"` it should also get changed to `\"erd5\"`.

Comment: Right now, this is a request for code. People do that for money as a day job (me included). This site is about helping fellow coders tackle their problems. So *what is* your problem exactly? What did you do, where are you stuck?

Comment: Setting aside the fact that that code won't compile, you should try to break your problem down into smaller pieces.

Comment: Did you forget to replace some erds?, e.g erd1?

Comment: @HimBromBeere no thats the thing that I'm trying to do, I want to change the `"erd..."` which has integer values > 3. `"erd..."` which have <= 3 integer value remains unchanged.

Comment: it looks like you want to use string.Replace() ? i am not sure what you trying to ask help for :-(

Comment: Find the index of *erd3* and start looking for any word that has *erd* after that index. Then use regex to find the numeric part and subtract 1 from it and replace the original. Keep doing this until finished. This is not hard and just requires writing some code. Have you written any code for this so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a small addon to [Dmitry Bychenko's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265824/284240), since OP wants to reduce all numbers that are greater than 3. You can use a method as `MatchEvaluator` with [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static string ReduceErdMatchEvaluator(Match m)
{
    int num;
    string numPart = m.Groups["item"].Value;
    bool validNum = int.TryParse(numPart, out num);
    if (validNum && num > 3)
        return $"\"erd{num - 1}\"";
    else
        return m.ToString();
}
```

Now the regex itself is very concise:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(text, "\"erd(?<item>[0-9]+)\"", new MatchEvaluator(ReduceErdMatchEvaluator));
```

Comment: I get an error `Unexpected character '$'` in the line `return $"\"erd{num - 1}\"";`

Comment: @Don_B: then you use an older .NET version. You can use `return "\"erd" + (num - 1) + "\"";`

Comment: @TimSchmeter Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `Substring` in order to preserve the prefix (up to the `"erd"3` border) intact and then *regular expressions* in order to perform `Replace`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string text = "Elijah Jordan Wood is an ...";

string border = "\"erd3\"";

int index = text.IndexOf(border);

string result = index < 0
  ? text // "\"erd3\"" has not been found, nothing to change
  : text.Substring(0, index + border.Length) +             // prefix (intact)
      Regex.Replace(text.Substring(index + border.Length), // subtraction: 
                    "\"erd(?<item>[0-9]+)\"",              //   pattern to find
                    m => "\"erd" +                         //   "erd" + item - 1 + "
                         (int.Parse(m.Groups["item"].Value) - 1).ToString() + 
                         "\"");
```

Comment: can you explain a bit, the process `result` in your code

Comment: but it does not work when say, `"erd5"` appears before the first `"erd3"`, that one does not change...

Comment: I want to replace all `"erdDIGIT"` where DIGIT > 3 regardless of how many times and where it is in the file...

Comment: @Don_B: you haven't mentioned that in your question: _"I want to reduce the numeric value from the strings \"erd...\" by 1 **after** the string \"erd3\""_

Comment: @TimSchmelter I believe I did in the NOTE: section of question

Comment: @Don_B: No, you have mentioned where the `Erd` could be, but you haven't said what should happen then. Since you said **after**, Dmitry and i thought that only the part after the first erd3 should be modified (no matter if the number is lower, equal or greater than 3).

Comment: @TimSchmelter my bad:(

Comment: @Don_B: so fix your question. You want to reduce every erd which number is greater than 3?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes